# How to adjust the spinners in a listview

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I have some spinner in a ListView(Left side some text and righ side spinner)
like this

[image]

everything is ok but i want spinners to be align like this

[image]

can someone please help to adjust the views..,.

Comment: adjust the gravity of spinner in the listitem xml file

Comment: @Ram: Thanks for the reply but sorry this doesn't work..,.

Comment: <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />    THIS IS MY SPINNER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner" 
 android:layout_width="150dp"//==> Set the width of the spinner. 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_marginRight="10sp" 
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
 android:focusable="false" 
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
 android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ram, I got what I want..,.It is hardcoded but fine..,.Thanks once again..,.